# Computing $\mathbb{P}\left(\left(U + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 > \frac{1}{2}\right)$ for uniform $U(0,1)$ random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I want to compute  $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left(U + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 > \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
Where $U$ is a $(0,1)$ uniform random variable. My attempt:

$$\mathbb{P}(U + \frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \mathbb{P}(U > \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{2}) = \frac{3 - \sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Is this correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I had a small error in the last step, corrected thanks to comment.

Comment: $1-\frac {\sqrt2 -1} 2=\frac {3 -\sqrt 2 } 2$.

Comment: Your result is correct, although I would have made a case differentiation: 1. $X\geq \frac12$ and 2. $X<\frac12$